# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid when process receives SIGTERM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sigterm

In my Rails app, I have a script that updates some records in the database.  When I send a SIGTERM to kill the script, it occasionally receives that signal while ActiveRecord is executing a query.  This leads to an ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid exception being raised.

I'd like to catch StatementInvalid exceptions that occur when they're they're the result of a SIGTERM and exit the script.  How can I tell that a StatementInvalid is occurring because of a signal and not for some other reason?

Comment: Is there something else you're looking for to close this question?

Answer (score 6):

If you trap the TERM signal, I believe you will avoid the exception. You can do this at the beginning of your script (or really anywhere for that matter, but you only need to do it once).

```
 Signal.trap("TERM") do
   Kernel.exit!
 end
```

The reason you get the StatementInvalid error is Ruby handles the signal by raising a SIGTERM exception at the place of current execution. ActiveRecord is catching the exception and rethrowing it as StatementInvalid. By setting a Signal handler, Ruby will execute your handler instead of raising an exception.

See the [Ruby Signal documentation](http://apidock.com/ruby/Signal) for more information.

Comment: Fixed, must use Kernel.exit! for this to work. Proof by example: http://gist.github.com/66735

Comment: Assuming that this type of exit is "normal", you probably want `Kernel.exit! true`. Taht way the process will exit with a status of 0.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this "script" is external to the Rails app (`script/runner` or similar?), so perhaps you can decouple the "signal handler" and "worker"? Eg can you fork a child process/thread/fiber/... to do the database update, and signal the parent to indicate "stop now"? Of course the parent will then have to "signal" the child to stop using some appropriate mechanism (not `SIGTERM` ;-)).

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact answer to the OP, however, you can control the exit point - the program will exit only after reaching the exit point defined by you.

```
time_to_die=false

# Prevent abrupt stopping of the daemon.
Signal.trap("TERM") { time_to_die=true; "SIG_IGN" }   

loop {
  .
  .
  exit_gracefully if time_to_die
  .
  .
}

def exit_gracefully
   #Cleaning up..
   $log.log "#{Time.now} TERM signal received. Exiting.."
   $db.close
   exit
 end
```